# How to left align figure?

Tags: r, knitr

With following chunk the left alignment doesn't work. The resulting map has still the same left border as without `fig.align='left'`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, british]{book}
\begin{document}
<<chunk.maps, fig.height=12, fig.width=21, out.width="6in", fig.align='left'>>=
library(knitr)
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl)
box()
@
\end{document}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Thanks,
Gerit

Comment: If you make the figure width much smaller, and then experiment with setting `fig.align` to center or right, you'll see that it _is_ left aligning the figure. It's just that the figure itself has an outer margin (that's just all white space). I thought that setting `xpd` might fix it, but it doesn't appear to.

Comment: Setting the left figure device margin (e.g. using `par(mai = ...)` moves it a bit further to the left, but probably not as much as you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to move my map at all. But thank you for putting time towards it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not because `fig.align="left"` does not work; as @joran said in the comments, it does work if you make the plot smaller. There are two problems that caused the artifact:

1. `par(mar)` is not 0 on the left margin by default; see `?par`; set `par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))` solves this problem
2. the plot was written into a paragraph, which has an amount of indentation by default in LaTeX (`\parindent`)

To make the plot touch the left margin, try this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
<<chunk.maps, fig.height=12, fig.width=21, out.width="6in", fig.align='left'>>=
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(wrld_simpl)
box()
@
\end{document}
```

If you are uncomfortable with setting `\parindent` to 0, you can restore it after the chunk.

Comment: Thank you! This works. I only had to set `par(mar=c(0, 0, 1.5, 0))` in order to show my title and now it looks fine. I also put `\begingroup` as well as `\endgroup` around the chunk - just to be sure not to mess with the rest of the document.